# How to add UITapGestureRecognizer to UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add UITapGestureRecognizer to my view with big UIWebView, but in works only if user tap not in UIWebView. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by implementing this method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView has it's own tap handling for opening links etc., therefor it doesn't handle "your" touches. You should subclass WebView and override tap handling. Good example [here](https://github.com/psychs/iphone-samples/tree/4028ab78af92ab17465338575b78ed80310a613f/WebViewTappingHack).